# com4J on Win64 connecting to a Win32 application

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, com4j

I have a 3rd-party Windows application that is 32-bit; it provides typelibs so I can connect to it from VBS, but only using the WScript.exe from %WINDIR%\SysWOW64.

I can generate the Java classes to access the COM objects with tlbimp.jar without any error, but when I run a program that uses these classes, I get

```
80040154 CoCreateInstance failed : Klasse nicht registriert : .\com4j.cpp:153
```

("Klasse nicht registriert" translates to "Class not registered").

Running the test sample from the com4J homepage (that one connecting to WSH) works fine.

Getting a 64-bit version of the 3rd-party application is not possible (at least not within the given timeframe).

I am using Java 8 64-bit from Oracle on Win7/64-bit for this task.

Is there any chance to get this running?

Comment: Have you tried using 32-bit Java 8 instead of 64-bit Java 8?

Comment: I have not tried yet to use 32-bit Java as the target environment has a requirement for 64-bit Java - although I do not know yet, why this was defined that way.